# How to avoid some javascript codes from executing if the browser is internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have some javascript codes

```
  var href = "demo.php";
    if(href)
    { 
        if($("#opacity")){
            $("#opacity").css({
                opacity: 0.5
            });
        }
        if (document.getElementById("layer")) {
            var ele = document.getElementById("layer");
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
  }
```

I want to avoid the codes

```
  if($("#opacity")){
            $("#opacity").css({
                opacity: 0.5
            });
        }
```

from executing if the browser is IE8 .. Please help . . .

Comment: Just in IE8 or all versions of IE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), to detect weither the browser is IE8, but it's considered as a bad practice:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) == 8)) {
  // ...
}
```

Instead of this, you should use [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), which will tell you if you can use `opacity` or not:

> opacity is equal to true if a browser can properly interpret the opacity style property. (It is currently false in IE, it uses alpha filters instead).
>   CSS3 spec

```
if (!$.support.opacity) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking `document.all` (true only for IE). But this is generally a bad idea. You should instead move your styles to classes (use filter for simulating opacity in IE), and just set those classes from your JS code. Additionally you can conditionally load CSS files for IE using `<!--[if IE 8]>` and so on

```
if(!document.all) {
    if($("#opacity")){
        $("#opacity").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould use the navigator object which contains all the information on the visitor's browser.

To test navigator object:

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

This code was an example on: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `$.browser` object:

```
if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) == 8)) {
    // this code will not execute on IE 8 but will run on other IE versions
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(href){
    if(!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "8.0")){
        if($("#opacity")){
            $("#opacity").css({
                opacity: 0.5
            });
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById("layer")) {
        var ele = document.getElementById("layer");
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's $.browser should do this just fine, but here's another solution

```
function isie() {
   var ie = false, 
       version = 100;
   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) var version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);if (version == 8) {var ie = true} return ie;
 }
```

returns true if IE8.

Also, jQuery css opacity is normalized and should work just fine in IE8.